# Flatten an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a collection like this:

```
Order //Collection
 |-OrderId
 |-DateOfOrder
 |-PartyName
 |-OrderDetails //Collection
 |    |-ItemName
 |    |-Quantity
 |    |-Rate
 |    |-Amount
 |-Dispatch //Collection
 |    |-InvoiceNo
 |    |-DateOfDispatch
 |    |-DispatchDetails //Collection
 |    |    |-ItemName
 |    |    |-Quantity
 |    |    |-Rate
 |    |    |-Amount
```

Now I want to flatten this collection, so that I can show data in below mentioned pattern:

```
OrderId | DateOfOrder | PartyName | InvoiceNo | DateOfDispatch | Dispatch ItemName | Dispatch Quantity | Dispatch Rate | Dispatch Amount
        |             |           |           |                |                   |                   |               |
        |             |           |           |                |                   |                   |               |
        |             |           |           |                |                   |                   |               |
        |             |           |           |                |                   |                   |               |
        |             |           |           |                |                   |                   |               |
        |             |           |           |                |                   |                   |               |
```

I have tried:

```
Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(orderService.GetAllOrders()
                                          .SelectMany(x => x.Dispatches)
                                          .SelectMany(x => x.DispatchDetails)
                                          .ToList()
                                        );
```

Comment: how are you displaying the items?

Comment: @Default Can you see a table like structure in question. That is how I want to display my items.

Comment: Are you using a `TreeView`, `DataGrid`, `ListBox`, `ListView` or something else?

Comment: Do the `DispatchDetail` item have knowledge of their parent? Likewise, do the `Dispatch` have knowledge of the `Order` parent? If so, how?

Comment: @Default I am using DataGrid. But I don't want to use RowDetails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between OrderDetails and DispatchDetails is not clear to me, and DispatchItemTransactions seems to be missing from your data structure. Anyway, I hope you find this simple approach useful:

```
foreach(var order in Orders)
    foreach(var dispatch in order.Dispatches)
        foreach(var dispatchDetail in dispatch.DispatchDetails)
        {
            // now construct your record object from order.OrderId, order.DateOfOrder, ... , dispatchDetail.Amount
        }
```

Comment: sorry, I edited the query in question. It was a typing mistake.

Comment: Is there a linq way of doing it??

Comment: juharr's second code pane seems to show exactly what you need ... the LINQ way

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you'll need to construct new `Order` and `Dispatch` objects.  Also query syntax will make this much easier to read.

```
Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order>(
    from o in orderService.GetAllOrders
    from d in o.Dispatches
    from dd in d.DispathDetails
    select new Order
    {
        OrderId = o.OrderId,
        DateOfOrder = o.DateOfOrder,
        PartyName = o.PartyName,
        Dispatches = new List<Dispatch> 
        { 
            new Dispatch
            {
                InvoiceNo = d.InvoiceNo
                DateOfDispatch = d.DateOfDispatch
                DispatchDetails = new List<DispatchDetail> { dd }
            }
        }           
    });
```

Though instead of a collection of `Order` you might want to just use an anonymous class instead

```
from o in orderService.GetAllOrders
from d in o.Dispatches
from dd in d.DispathDetails
select new 
{
    OrderId = o.OrderId,
    DateOfOrder = o.DateOfOrder,
    PartyName = o.PartyName,
    InvoiceNo = d.InvoiceNo
    DateOfDispatch = d.DateOfDispatch,
    DispatchItemName = dd.ItemName,
    DispatchQuantity = dd.Quantity,
    DispatchRate = dd.Rate,
    DispatchAmount = dd.Amount
}
```

Comment: Does not want a List<Dispatch>

Comment: @Paparazzi I have not idea what your comment means.

Comment: I did.  The OP apprently wants `Order` objects where the `Dispatches` and `DispatchItemTransactions` have been flattened, so I still don't see where your comment comes into play here.

Comment: Fine - we don't have the same definition of flatten

Comment: @juharr I am sorry. I had a typing mistake in my query in question. Can you please see the question once again?

Comment: The second that does not have List<Dispatch>.  That would be what I mean by "Does not want a List<Dispatch>".

Comment: @Paparazzi OK, but the OP wanted to populate a `ObservableCollection<Order>` and the `Order` class contains a collection of `Dispatch`.  So to put the "flattened" data into those models you'd have to create lists that have on item each.

Comment: Yes there was some possible inconsistencies as in many questions.  If you considered flattened and the output it was very clear to me.